# Скачивание файла в Service/IntentService и отображение процесса скачивания

Tags: java, android, service, download

У меня есть плеер, в котором можно скачивать песни. Для скачивания на данный момент я использую `IntentService`, который выглядит вот так:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService implements ApiResponse.ApiFailureListener {

    public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_STARTED = "com.example.uncolor.action.DOWNLOAD_STARTED";
    public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED = "com.example.uncolor.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED";
    public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE = "com.example.uncolor.action.DOWNLOAD_FAILURE";

    public static final String ARG_MUSIC = "music";

    public DownloadService() {
        super("Download Service");
    }

    private BaseMusic music;

    @Override
    public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
        App.Log("onStart service");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        App.Log("onHandleIntent service");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            music = extras.getParcelable("music");
            if(music != null) {
                  App.Log("download url: " + music.getDownload());
            }
        }

        if(music == null){
            App.Log("music null");
            sendIntent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE);
            return;
        }
        String artist = "";
        String title = "";
        if(music.getArtist() != null){
            artist = music.getArtist();
        }

        if(music.getTitle() != null){
            title = music.getTitle();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                        artist + " - " + title + ".mp3");
        String uriFromFile = Uri.fromFile(outputFile).toString();
        App.Log("Uri from file: " + uriFromFile);
        initDownload();
    }

    private void initDownload() {
        App.Log("init download");
        onDownloadStarted(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_STARTED);
        Api.getSource().downloadFile(music.getDownload()).enqueue(ApiResponse
                .getCallback(getDownloadCallback(), this));

    }

    private ApiResponse.ApiResponseListener<ResponseBody> getDownloadCallback() {
        return new ApiResponse.ApiResponseListener<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ResponseBody result) {
                try {
                    downloadFile(result);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
        App.Log("download file");
        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
        long fileSize = body.contentLength();
        InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
        String artist = "";
        String title = "";
        if(music.getArtist() != null){
            artist = music.getArtist();
        }

        if(music.getTitle() != null){
            title = music.getTitle();
        }
        File outputFile =
                new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                        artist + " - " + title + ".mp3");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        long total = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int timeCount = 1;
        while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            int totalFileSize = (int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
            double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));

            int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            Download download = new Download();
            download.setTotalFileSize(totalFileSize);

            if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {

                download.setCurrentFileSize((int) current);
                download.setProgress(progress);
                timeCount++;
            }

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        App.Log("output path: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        music.setLocalPath(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        onDownloadComplete(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        bis.close();
        App.Log("download complete");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        App.Log("onDestroy Download service");
    }


    private void sendIntent(String action) {
        App.Log("send intent");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(ARG_MUSIC, music);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void onDownloadComplete(String action) {
        App.Log("onDownloadComplete");
        sendIntent(action);
    }

    private void onDownloadStarted(String action) {
        App.Log("onDownloadStarted");
        sendIntent(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int code, String message) {
        App.Log("Download failure");
        sendIntent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Проблема данного класса в том, что я не могу узнать прогресс скачивания во время загрузки(1%, 2%...и так далее) и отобразить его в `Activity`. Хотелось бы узнать, каким способом лучше скачивать файлы. Может лучше будет использовать обычный `Service`? Нужно как то формировать очередь скачиваний... Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для скачивая я рекомендую использовать **DownloadManager** [почитать можно тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager). Его можно настроить так, чтобы отображалось уведомление о загрузки файла и как раз подходит для твоих целей, складывать в очередь загрузки.

Получить **DownloadManager** можно:

```
((DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE))
```

Пример использования (**request** - твой запрос):

```
Request request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("твой URL"))
            //Устанавливаем уведомление, которое будет отображать процесс загрузки        
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)

            .setTitle("твое название файла")
            //папка назначения куда скачается файл
            .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
                context,
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName + fileExtension
            )
        //Складываем твой запрос в очередь для скачивания
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```